# Print Hamlet's monologue using as few characters as possible

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

The task here is to print the text below, using **as few characters as possible** in your code. You can't use any external resource. (file, stdin, network)

```
To be, or not to be: that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,
And by opposing end them? To die: to sleep;
No more; and by a sleep to say we end
The heart-ache and the thousand natural shocks
That flesh is heir to, 'tis a consummation
Devoutly to be wish'd. To die, to sleep;
To sleep: perchance to dream: ay, there's the rub;
For in that sleep of death what dreams may come
When we have shuffled off this mortal coil,
Must give us pause: there's the respect
That makes calamity of so long life;
For who would bear the whips and scorns of time,
The oppressor's wrong, the proud man's contumely,
The pangs of dispriz'd love, the law's delay,
The insolence of office and the spurns
That patient merit of the unworthy takes,
When he himself might his quietus make
With a bare bodkin? Who would these fardels bear,
To grunt and sweat under a weary life,
But that the dread of something after death,
The undiscover'd country from whose bourn
No traveller returns, puzzles the will
And makes us rather bear those ills we have
Than fly to others that we know not of?
Thus conscience does make cowards of us all;
And thus the native hue of resolution
Is sicklied o'er with the pale cast of thought,
And enterprises of great pith and moment
With this regard their currents turn away,
And lose the name of action.--Soft you now!
The fair Ophelia! Nymph, in thy orisons
Be all my sins remember'd.
```

Comment: Don't you mean *monologue*?

Comment: @feersum Don't you mean *soliloquy*? :P

Comment: @Geobits Touché.

Comment: I'd just like to give a reason for my downvote: I don't like generic kolmogorov complexity challenges unless there is some internal structure to cleverly utilize, and I really dislike character counting golfs.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. We've had similar challenges before, unfortunately this one doesn't add anything different. Stick around, answer a few questions to find out what we're about, and feel free to post your next question at our sandbox for feedback: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/15599

Comment: My downvote is because you count in characters, not bytes.

Comment: @steveverrill I search before I asked this, but as I didn't I haven't found anything. The question that this is a duplicate of has a title that doesn't even hint that it might be related to my question, possibly that's why I didn't find it. Still, thanks!

Comment: @JanDvorak Tell that to the guys at Ericsson, this in one of their programming competitions: http://www.ericssonbajnoksag.hu/regebbi_feladatok

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, <s>713</s> 683 characters

We're counting by characters so here's the usual Unicode encoding approach. I'm sure this can be beaten, but at least it's less than half as many characters as the output.

```
"=迗拢쌜僨糌ࢬꭖ杋鏊ꦓ廃啒⼬ᏸꛒ멉尬䳉藋底淡蟖ꣃ⪖恉囻ꮠⶠ榯൨鞺㹑悩眷ဋ㟯ㅕ葡Ż㼡惽Т託⹡嫰뵴䕞凿绸䷛䴽繋㐚挻ᙶ᪻뼶䌼냞ോ貿ꐯ欲鄁卒梷몧臡ꙉꐰ臸惽ệ昣䙍樬ᓜ녖谴鈦⃇炣膊Ე戭⟣䌮ꆰ躍➥կ语鄂셸ⷽⁿ덝곋䚴䚗Ḹ硅㺁餌쀎柁ᛔ礳괰蚴變㿢䅋砤鈴綸䨜᾽㓔䘅䊶䭚⦑럜䧑䔠⳾뇾䴓ꣽ鎋੩呝䓔ᇽἰ䗚笨簛䀣䲮攌꘦↢ኲㄉ⥈䎺韧᭩滥叒㰥ꬔ懭彼垥丼됑艨ᒝ荶뵴枀膛㛏닱関㵃踫⹦瀗媂㴫꺼柝➍ꜙ纫弡ꔕ㦂蹘ꬃ粅ᛧ熄寝㎍衰飔㩏鈅廀裝굗猪맊␰例㘇ꓶ᫋⟗㟔獇⍨ꉔ뵯瓗ℎ岻摔撎偱紁꽓澤䔷刪㒰墄㰑쀨ꦞ沣뤣葇欕鎨빵ဟ赊剡篠壃ఌ忎꺉鴩绘腀뉂每倢觌びው錵ꏅ儅몧瑳갎媢㗿陣欿᫉ꋿ週䰧鉝깊屌軌먝궔꘹ҙ伔肢⨘緍㰑㐩삭善เⴹ뫑勂㣗曝㛊瘐蠚椂ỿꖴ⎫ᶬ鐸它蒗ؑ謅໐뮦ꩇℇ虇ヽ襟餰塹媬蕥偃⒭躧ꩆ꣢麡翲ⷜ緤飆㛉鴳㾂偾ᖈ欍㩻䦛ꄆꏝ꣭䠦᭳㭱囃㣝䥀鿆䴹෽蝩荲輳蓆娠啃帶ᮾᨍ쀶ѱⴣ㻝順᫰掽紈걉壬虾撆Ⅴ軚䀥ᚑF㠡㞮ᨣ溹뷝欬듺㡧玌딿섄ଷ럫㏵椉䴚ጪ⾗瞾䕼效㠐翢Տ须䈲蘸อ괟㿬む攩糼烏뼊ⷫ庁诔뀗瀦䴇鳨匿ò韑祋夯稚骪愫蕁렒蒔룳πབྷℇଉ簿ّ뺦謃刨㫳ᔥ槦ᑃ璽皩宩傜䷗᥁ꊙ庉놨ꠑᯋ撿ᰃ⧹ⷅ瓴눥᮶â䏶뒾ञ代뫵ਫ㙺Ἑధॆ偟끎녘ৈ黗돃Ὄ檮㢈괿哟繹ꈥ垌喞ᘜ齈㒹뭹ᴴ轳浬曥瑾級꫼ᡊᴮ留㝸螱Ḵ嗳汏ᔔ藁嫜≵୛掣Ẁ恪⍩슅手彶䤇萴櫹ວჲ⽢а琨늪ㇲᭈ쇰ӳ㧠㥡놀Ꙭ碐ゼ⎴릊⍢蠐贈㧑请骰곮쀕렳ಊ祟㽖葬汓䢢兘뢺韴泧馆净벏ᵢ䕋僛♃⩖䎹ᑟ㓆虑鈃ڳ눼絇移ꝴ匯䇸㓀♔⳶㓧෴較õ乛ᔫ欚嗶᥄ꈢャ✉Ꝼ拂橳˯㶲ʤ댯ᡃ볿籚䊋釗‭␶傍궔樥泤趡鮚㺅卫㲴汒穿ⵑ衙ꞅ修쉚皨ƽ┐꣚漛༻ꔤ꾰䖓澐꣗輘醵醸乯ᦳ䕴䛯词麈鏡棧ᚒ᳜朝ꙧꬫ諒㜑瑕⨱㴥뎋面ᬀ滯憮௦庰民눿隆磁꼓詮䡎䵩费㤋腔杦薎㱿ᇆ韗騏⧢盚븎"5e4b128b:c
```

For some reason I end up with a leading `a` after decoding, which I need to remove first.